# contacting an address possible?

Tags: addresses, message

this might sound stupid for some, maybe even hilarious, have a laugh but please be kind when replying:

the question: is there a way to contact or send a message to an ETH-address?

my issue: I only just recently noticed, that I managed to send my ETH balance to a wrong address. Yup, I actually did that. I checked on etherscan.io and the balance is still there, so I guess the address has no idea that it received ETH coins... Any ideas on how to contact creator of the addresses?
You might ask why: well at best to get my ETH back (yes I actually think that to be a possibility) and at least to let the person know about the balance...
cheers

Comment: etherscan shows only one Ether transaction 991 days ago ...

Comment: That address doesn't have an outgoing transaction so it is possible there's no private key associated with it.

Comment: @Ismael does that mean the balance might be lost in the 'matrix'? What about the Token addresses? Is there a chance to contact the user through those addresses? THANKS

Comment: @MarkG If nobody has the private key then the balance is lost. It is unfeasible to seach for it with current computers. If there exists an owner unless he associated they address with his identity on a social network it is unlikely you will be able to contact him.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you gave the wrong address. But it doesn't make much difference.

There is no direct way to contact an address. The only way to send "messages" to an address is to send a transaction with data. So, in theory, you could send a transaction with a specific message in the data section, but in reality it's unlikely that anyone would read that message (the message would need to be decoded).

There are various services around which provide some services for addresses but it's also very unlikely that the user would've participated in some of those services. Also I can't remember any of the service names, but there's something like emailing an Ethereum address and stuff like that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

@madjackal and @lauripeltonen and @ismael
thank you all for the help and kind comments - just a quick follow up as it might be really funny to you all:
I initially thought that I had sent my funds to a wrong address.
I had printed a paper wallet over two years ago to store my ETH offline.
My funds were not there at that address, so obviously I figured I had sent my funds to a wrong address somehow, well...
...turns out I had forgotten where I had sent my funds to :)
the address the funds are at, is actually mine, just not the paper one but my trezor instead - only just realised that a few minutes ago when I was installing Exodus wallet, paired it with trezor and I saw my ETH balance - what a f***ing relief that was :)

Answer (score 0):

Message can be send to the eth address but the receiver also has to login and check for the messages here https://app.wallets.chat/

Answer (score 0):

If the wallet you want to contact has an NFT collection, you can try and send them a message as an NFT. You could mint one on your own, or use a service like [jpegme.com](https://jpegme.com).

I had this same issue of sending Eth to the wrong address. Its embarrassing but I'm sure it happens often. I'd also recommend using ENS domains if possible in the future.

Answer (score 0):

all of this is not correct! etherscan.io now has a "chat" feature.. ive been trying to get 200 matic that i accidentally sent on ETH network instead of Poly network.. I've messaged the wallet .. but I dont think anyone regularly checks it.. my erroneous send is the only transaction in the wallets history since creation.  But... it is possible!

[image: at the bottom of etherscan.io's page.. see?]

Comment: As you can see at the bottom of the "Products & Services" column at the bottom of the page, it has "Blockscan Chat".. Just make sure you have an etherscan.io account and that you have a wallet connected that has an actual transaction history.. most wallet addresses will not accept messages from other addresses if their associated wallet doesn't have actual transactions in it's history.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/96090)